# TFS Backlogs Iteration Group By

Tags: tfs, iteration, azure-devops, backlog

I made a new category called Deliverable and I would like to have the option to sort by *that* in the "Group By" dropdown which is displayed when viewing a iteration.

What would need to be changed in the Agile template to make this possible?

*Currently you can only group by People or Stories. I want to add a new category to group by.*

[image: GroupBy Screenshot]

*Using TFS 2018 Update 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [Add a portfolio backlog level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-portfolio-backlogs) first then try below steps (`RequirementCategory` for example here ) :

1. Export the **ProcessConfiguration** XML file: (See [Import and
   export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration))

   - `witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:c:\temp\ProcConf.xml`
2. Edit the corresponding category elements (e.g.: `RequirementBacklog`
   here) like this (Set the value of `pluralName` to `Deliverable` ):

   - `<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Deliverable" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">`
3. Import the **ProcessConfiguration** XML file,

   - `witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:c:\temp\ProcConf.xml`

**Note that, if you want to reflect the custom WITs on the `RequirementCategory` here, you also need to add the WITs to that category:**

1. Export the **category** xml file:

   - `witadmin exportcategories /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:c:\temp\Catagory.xml`
2. Edit the category xml file to add the WITs which you want to be reflected in this category (e.g.: I added **Bug** in `RequirementCategory` except the default "**User Story**"):

   - `<CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" name="Requirement Category">
     <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
     <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
     </CATEGORY>`
3. Import the the **category** xml file:

   - `witadmin importcategories /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:c:\temp\Catagory.xml`

Check if that works. Below screenshot for your reference.

See [Add a work item type to a backlog and board](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards#wits-as-requirements) for details.

---

Besides, you can also try the extension : [**Query based boards**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards).
This extension allows you to visualize the result of work item queries on a board. The order by clauses of the query are respected on the board.

After installing the extension, navigte to the Work hub, and select Queries. When opening a query, a new tab called Board is available to visualize the results on a boad.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to add, that whatever WIT is the DEFAULTWORKITEM in a category is what color scheme that category inherits. Thanks for the detailed answer.